# How To Get Domain non built-in Groups using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

i have a c# function that gives me all of domain group's name :

```
public static List<String> ListAllDomainGroups()
{
    List<String> groups = new List<string>();

    // create your domain context
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
    GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

    // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

    // find all matches
    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
    {

        // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
        //listBox2.Items.Add(found.ToString());
        groups.Add(found.ToString());
    }

    return groups;
}
```

function returns about 70 names including :

**WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_**

**Administrators**

**Users**

**Guest**

**Print Operations**

**Backup Operators**

**Replicator**

**IIS_IUSRS**

**Remote Desktop Users**

...
...

(then groups i defined)

how can i get only the **groups that i have defined** in my AD and not the built-in groups ?

Comment: Well, I believe you have 2 option here. The first one is all those groups are specified in msdn. Create an exclude list of the groups. The second option is to based on SID. SID contains domain SID part and RID - the last integer part. DC increments it and assign to a security principal. So, I guess default groups should have same rid in every domain. For example, in theory you can query objects with rid > some number. Not sure if it works, but you can check it